# How to make `script` start and end automatically when working in a certain directory?

Tags: shell, typescript

I want to use the `script` program to record my session any time that I am working within a certain directory, such as my `~/projects` directory.

So for example, I would `cd` into `~/projects`, and `script` would automatically start recording everything to a log in that directory. As soon as I leave `~/projects`, then `script` would stop. Also,  `~/projects` has many subdirectories; the log file needs to remain at the top level of the directory tree.

Any ideas on how this would be implemented? Even better, is there a method of implementing this that would also work with other programs easily?

Comment: Just about the only thing I can think of would be to do something like `export PROMPT_COMMAND="if [[ "$HOME/projects" == "$PWD" ]]; then unset PROMPT_COMMAND; script; fi` in your `.profile`, but it won't automatically exit and will only trigger if you go into the top directory

Comment: I've used a similar technique for a custom function which has slightly different actions depending on the `$PWD`, but its triggered manually. I was thinking about aliasing the `cd` command in such a way that after changing to the desired directory it also performs this check and starts/ends `script` appropriately, but I wasn't sure if this might cause unforeseen problems. I'm not yet familiar with other ways to have actions performed in the background based on the `$PWD`

Comment: You could override the `cd` command with a shell function that does `command cd "$@"` and then checks `$PWD` and starts `script` if the user is in the right directory. The problem is exiting `script`, because it fires up its own shell subprocess. The custom `cd` shell function could issue an `exit` as soon as the user moves elsewhere, but since the current directory is local to each subprocess, the invocation of `cd` that takes the user out of the special directory would not be able to actually change his/her working directory.